# FBReader: How do I get it to display partial images?

Tags: linux, ebook

I've been using FBReader so far for reading e-books, but my problem with it is how it handles images. Whenever there's an image, it isn't displayed until all of it can be displayed (i.e. it won't show if you haven't scrolled down far enough) and scrolling isn't smooth because the image is treated as one line.

Is there a way to change this so that it displays the partially visible images?

If there is not a way to change this, I am open to software suggestions to use as an alternative (I'm using the Linux Desktop version with GTK).

I have already tried Calibre, but I find that it's too bloated. It takes ages to start up, and I don't want a directory for all my e-books...

Comment: Why don't you contact FBReader Support at support@geometerplus.com ?

Comment: @harrymc: The only problem is that the desktop version isn't under active development. It's worth a try, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you on?

FBreader (the one I know in Android) will not render that way, you're stuck with jerky scrolling, but in return the application is small and efficient with memory.

On an android phone, FBreader stays my favorite, though I must admit I have not tried many other readers available (just a handfull). On an iPhone my favorite is [Blio](http://www.meetblio.com/) which is also available for PC and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blio.androidreader&hl=en) (with a higher version than mine). The PC version does not work well with epub (it uses xps which is not common, and it often has trouble converting epub to xps).

If you think Calibre is bloated, you probably don't have to try [Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/nl/products/digitaleditions/) or [sony reader](http://ebookstore.sony.com/download/). I guess [ibis](http://ibisreader.com/) may be more for you (though I have only evaluated the web-based version).

There is a list of reviews with screenshots for different platforms [here](http://www.jedisaber.com/eBooks/Readers.shtml#EPUBReader).

Comment: I forgot Android was based on Linux :p. Sorry, I'm using the Linux Desktop version with GTK. ibis doesn't appear to be available for desktops. I tried the EPUBReader plugin and so far it works great. No scrolling problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused about ibis. Is it an online reader?

Comment: Ibis for the PC is online only, but for mobile devices (Android and iPhone) it can be used offline (though I think it still uses or runs inside a browser since its all javascript as far as I can see). The current version of the EPUBReader is indeed very good, I tried an earlier version before which was not as mature but I guess I'll be using this one.